# Transactions in programming for TFS

Tags: tfs, transactions, sdk

I am developing a small application for a specific build-automation task using C# and TFS SDK 2008.

I wonder if we can run transactional code against TFS tasks; for example I want to check-in a change and then create a label all automatically, if the label creation fails due to some failure I want to roll back the last change I made.

Is this available, or I should code this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to code this- MSBuild has support for this though.

Your first step is checking in the file.

```
<Target Name="Checkin" />  
<Exec Command="Command_To_Checkin_File"  />  
</Target>
```

Next step is to create a label.  Here though, on error, we will rollback the checkout.

```
<Target Name="CreateLabel" />  
<Exec Command="Command_To_Create_Label"  />  
<OnError ExecuteTargets="UndoCheckout" />
</Target>
```

And finally, add the command to undo the checkout.

```
<Target Name="UndoCheckout" />  
<Exec Command="Command_To_Undo_Checkout"  />  
</Target>
```

Examples of checkin, checkout and undo:

For all

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)" Command=" />
```

Checkin

```
$(TF) checkin /comment:&quot;Auto-Build: Version Update&quot; /noprompt /override:&quot;Auto-Build: Version Update&quot; /recursive " />
```

Checkout

```
$(TF) checkout /recursive $(FilePath)" />
```

Undo

```
$(TF) undo /noprompt /recursive $(FilePath)"/>
```

Comment: Do the Commands "Command_To_Checkin_File", "Command_To_Create_Label", and "Command_To_Undo_Checkout" already exist? if no then why not just create a "try catch" block? 
I thought of more intrinsic functionality built-in in TFS SDK for transactions and rollbacks.

Comment: Yes, those commands already exist. The reason I wrote it that way was because the command varies related to the path. I should have just written it out and shown the path area as changing. I will update the answer

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does. I would recommend breaking this in to two tasks. From the 1st task return a success/failure code, this will be very easy to achieve using MS BUILD. If the first task succeeds then execute the 2nd task.

HTH

Cheers, Tarun

Comment: The problem wasn't with the first task succeeding, it had to do with creating the label failing.  In this instance, you can't passback that label creation pass/fail to an already executed step.